# Gulp-nodemon and watch task

Tags: node.js, gulp, nodemon

I'm trying to create my build flow using gulp and nodemon. The objective is to watch sass files and compile them to css, and also restart node application when server file changes.

My gulpfile.js:

```
gulp.task('sass', function(){
  return gulp.src(sassFilesTobeProcessed).
  pipe(sass()).
  pipe(concat('ready_stylesheet.css')).
  pipe(gulp.dest('express/public/stylesheets'))
})

gulp.task('watch', function(){
  return gulp.watch(allSassFiles, ['sass']);
})

gulp.task('serve', function(){
  return nodemon({
    script: 'express/app.js',
  }).on('start', ['watch'])
  .on('change', ['watch'])
  .on('restart', function(){
      console.log('restarted');
    })
})
```

The watch task is working fine, files are compiled after change. But changes in my app.js server file doesn't trigger server restart. When I comment the `.on` statements it starts to work fine (server reloads), but then of course sass files are no longer observed. I assume hence, there is some conflict between these two, which I cannot discover. Appreciate any help! My OS - Windows 7, node 4.2.6, nodemon 1.9.1

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use a task dependency instead of `.on(event)` to start your `watch` task:

```
gulp.task('serve', ['watch'], function(){
  return nodemon({
    script: 'express/app.js',
  })
  .on('restart', function(){
    console.log('restarted');
  })
})
```

Answer (score 0):

emit the restart event with nodemon

```
const cfg = require('../config')
const gulp = require('gulp')
const nodemon = require('nodemon')
const gnodemon = require('gulp-nodemon')

gulp.task('nodemon', ['ts', 'json'], () => {
  gnodemon({
    script: cfg.paths.main,
    tasks: ['ts', 'json'],
    ext: 'js',
    watch: [cfg.paths.src],
    // para no alterar el entorno de prodicion con test
    env: {'NODE_ENV': process.env.NODE_ENV !== 'production'
      ? process.env.NODE_ENV || 'development' : 'development'}
  })
  .on('start', ['mocha'])
})

gulp.task('default', ['nodemon'], () => {
  gulp.watch(cfg.paths.src, (event) => nodemon.emit('restart'))
})
```